# Why is the word "problem" not allowed in the question title?

Tags: discussion, title, question-restrictions

I created the question [Excel when connected to external data: "We found a problеm with some content in [file]"](https://superuser.com/questions/1121810/excel-when-connected-to-external-data-we-found-a-pr0blem-with-some-content-in/), trying to summarise the issue in the title.

The (shortened) error message precisely identifies the specific issue I experience, however the word "problem" is not allowed in the question title, so I resorted to using l33t-speak.

I could have used a more generic description, but that would mean visitors wouldn't conclusively know from the title, if the questions concerns the issue they're experiencing, or a similar issue.

This seems like a silly and counter-productive restriction, which potentially makes perfectly valid questions harder to find by searching.

Comment: In a nutshell: the few false positives as in your case are nothing compared to the thousands of "plz solve my problem" titles we would be getting if it will be allowed.